# Undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.chat')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I have written is

```
import {
    Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

   <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{
        Actions.chat({
        name:{this.state.name},
        });
   }}>
    <Text style={styles.bottonText}>
   Next
   </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

But i am continously getting error with `Actions.chat();`. what else do i need to think about?

Comment: What is `chat`?

Comment: Need more code: How and Where did you write all your `Actions` routes? Also post the code as is, `TouchableOpacity` is within `render()`, and `render()` is within a `class`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for **Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {
    Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Home extends Component{
    state={
        name:"",
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Enter your name :
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.nameInput}
                    placeholder='Rafin Karki'
                    onChangeText={(text)=>{
                        this.setState({
                            name:text,
                        })
                    }}
                    value={this.state.name}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{
                        Actions.chat({
                            name:{this.state.name},
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Text style={styles.bottonText}>
                        Next
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    title:{
        marginTop: 20,
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    nameInput:{
        padding:5,
        height:40,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#000000',
        margin:20
    },
    bottonText:{
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize:20,
    },
});
```

Code for **App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

import {
    Router,
    Scene,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import {
    Platform
} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Scene key='root' style={{ paddingTop:Platform.OS==='ios'?64:54}}>
                    <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home'/>
                    <Scene key='chat' component={Chat} title='Chat'/>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

And **Chat.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Chat extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Hello {this.props.name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```